# Redirect errors using angular 4 on nginx

Tags: angular, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

While using PathLocationStrategy for Angular apps after the authentication redirection I am getting 404 error on Nginx.

The bowser gets redirected from /login page to Authorize page in another domain and after successful validation it gets redirected to http://127.0.0.1:4200/homepage&access_token=&token_type=bearer&state=XYZ&expires_in=3599.

But I think as ngnix tries to identify it as separate page I am getting a 404 not found error. Also if I am trying to access the page directly like http://127.0.0.1:4200/homepage I am getting 404, but when navigating from the app its working.

Is there any setting in nginx to resolve this error ? (FYI: I have used Ngnix rewrite rules but still not able to resolve the issue)

Comment: Post your nginx config, and access+error logs from nginx

Comment: I am using this rewrite rule for Nginx

`location / {
            try_files $uri $uri index.html;
        }`